# git rebase master results in master commits on top of branch commits

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-rebase

I'm working in a branch that was branched off master awhile ago. Since then, a number of features have been added to master that I would like to pick up in my branch. In the past, I've used `git rebase master` to rebuild my branch by replaying the commits in my branch on top of master. However, this currently isn't working as it should.

Here's what I'm doing

```
my-branch shows 63 commits ahead, 10 commits behind master - on github
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my-branch
git rebase master my-branch
```

During the rebase, I hit only one merge conflict which is easily fixed. After the rebase finishes, I notice that some files reflect what is in `master` not `my-branch`. I can't, for the life of me, figure out what I'm doing wrong. Is this caused by the fact that the branch is both ahead and behind master? This seems like a fairly common situation, so I don't feel that it would break the rebase workflow.

I've also tried doing a git merge, which results in the exact same end state for `my-branch`.

-- Edit 10/18/19 --

I've narrowed the problem down to the following, which I didn't see until digging deeper.This is what happened

It turns out the changes in my-branch were merged into master a few months ago. After that, another branch absent of those changes was merged into master, effectively removing the changes. This means the commit that those changes are in isn't in the commit list for the rebase. I thought I saw the commit in the list, but the problem was it was a very generic message that I simply overlooked. Since this issue doesn't seem to be a problem with git or how I was using rebase, I'm going to accept the current answer and leave it here for future reference.

Comment: Without more information, we cannot tell you conclusively what is happening. A merge or rebase "merges" changes between two branches.  So, if `file1` was changed in `master` and not in `my-branch` then the result of the merge will be the version from `master`. Another thing to look at is if `my-branch` was originally split from `master`.  If not, your merge operation may be attempting to merge more than you are expecting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `my-branch` wasn't directly branched off master. More like a branch from a branch from a branch from master. But isn't `git rebase master my-branch` suppose to play all `master` commits first, THEN `my-branch` commits, or is it not that simple? Also, I'm happy to add any logs that would help better understand the situation.

Comment: when you perform a merge or rebase, git finds the newest commit in common between the two branches.  The is called the "merge base." Then all changes in commits in one branch--all the way back to the merge base-- are applied to the tip of the other branch.  For a merge, a single merge commit is added to the target branch which contains all the changes from the other branch, going back to the merge base. For rebase, commit are re-played on top of the source branch and the target branch is updated to point to the last commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your branch was started off from master, what you should run is (after having checked out your branch, as you do in the instructions):

```
git rebase master
```

Comment: `git rebase master` and `git rebase master my-branch` are effectively the same thing